# How to edit an existing theme with dugway

Tags: bigcartel

I have dugway installed, but I do not want to create a new theme but edit an existing theme. How would I go about doing this.

Thanks

David Wright

Answer (score 0):

You can download any existing Big Cartel theme and use it locally with Dugway right here: https://github.com/bigcartel-themes

Just click the 'Clone to desktop' button on any of the repositories, or use the GitHub app / command line to clone them on your computer. From there you can make changes to the theme and edit it to your liking, just keep in mind that Dugway does have limitations (like being able to edit theme settings, modifying javascript, and more): https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway#known-issues--limitations